# Retrieving values from multiple keys in Firebase using AngularFire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I am just getting started with angularFire2. I have some Firebase data structured as follows:

```
{
    "user-friends": {
        "-userkey1": {
            "-userkey2": true,
            "-userkey3": true
        }
    },

    "users": {
        "-userkey1": {
            "uid": "id1",
            "uname": "Jim Yu"
        },
        "-userkey2": {
            "uid": "id2",
            "uname": "Bob Smith"
        },
        "-userkey3": {
            "uid": "id3",
            "uname": "Jane Doe"
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I can retrieve the data in `user-friends` node for `-userkey1`, which returns

```
   "-userkey1": {
        "-userkey2": true,
        "-userkey3": true
    }
```

Then I want to be able to get the`uname` of each key, and store that in a variable that would be bind to the view.

I'm a bit unsure of how to go about that last step specifically using angularFire2..or if there is a angular/firebase specific approach/helper method to solving this.

so far this is what I have, however once I loop through each key and attempt to push the username into an array, the console logs the first keys `uname` but then screams`cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

```
userFriends(userkey: string){
    console.log("userKey=" + userkey)
    var getUsrFriends = this.afDB.list("https://myfirebaseurl.com/user-friends/" + userkey
    ).subscribe( data => {
        data.forEach(friendKey => {
            console.log(friendKey.$key) //my instinct tells me looping through the keys and storing in an array is not a optimal solution
            var getUserInfo = this.afDB.object("https:/myfirebaseurl.com/users/" + friendKey.$key, {
            }).subscribe( u => {
                console.log(u.uname)
                this.friendsList.push(u.uname) // <- undefined error 
            })    
        });       
    })   
}

<ng-container  *ngIf="showView == 'friend'">
    <ion-list *ngFor="let friend of friendsList">
        <h3>{{friend}}</h3>
    </ion-list>
</ng-container>
```

EDIT:  The undefined error was actually caused by not initializing the `friendsList` Array properly.

```
export class UserPage {
  friendsList: string[] = []
 // constructor, etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is really quick, so making multiple calls is not too bad.

Using your current data structure, this code will work:

```
// Outside firebase calls
let scope = this;

...
var getUserInfo = this.afDB.object("https:/myfirebaseurl.com/users/" + friendKey.$key, {}).take(1).subscribe( u => {
    console.log(u.uname)
    scope.friendsList.push(u.uname) // <- undefined error 
})
...
```

`this`, once inside the Firebase promise is reserved by that promise and means something different than the regularly reserved `this` of global component variables.

Also, use `take(1)` before the subscribe because you are only wanting to retrieve those values once and not to continue listening.

---

An alternate method would be to restructure your database to make faster queries in a tradeoff for more data storage. Instead of storing the just the user reference inside `user-friends` you can store the whole `user`. But I would advise the first option.

Comment: Thanks @theblindprophet. I also realized I had not initialized  friendsList array properly. I only had declared the type.